# This script won't execute

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE Mango AS Manga     
SELECT ID,Salary   
FROM demoScript.boss.Customers
```

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Remove the MANGA and you are good

Comment: I get an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.                 when I remove the Manga. I am using MSSQL server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,Salary
INTO Mango
FROM demoScript.boss.Customers
```

Then you'll need to manually add primary key, foreign keys, constraints, indexes, etc.

Comment: But the Table Mango needs to be created and given an alias. I tried your suggestion but without secces.

Comment: Thank you very much. You misspelt demoScript thats why the code did not execute. Now it works